# What type of code is this? how/can I get javascript to recognize it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to html and javascript, learning on the go to help update a website for the company i work for.  The company does it through a browser program/interface called NETKIT / Adobe Business Catalyst.  You can create pages for new projects which are called webapps and you can classify them to different groups for sorting, e.g. Water projects, Civil projects.  Once you create a database of webapps, you can insert this line of code in html which will produce a thumbnail list of projects for which you've filtered for:

```
{module_webapps id="3388" resultsPerPage="20" filter="all" rowCount="3" template="/Templates/projectspage.tpl"}
```

So this code will show all projects in the database in rows of 3's, 20 results per page etc.  It works fine when I insert it by itself in html, but I want to use it in javascript, however when i do it doesn't recognize the code and it doesn't show on the page.

For example:

html:

```
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

Script:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '{module_webapps id="3388" resultsPerPage="20" filter="all" rowCount="3" template="/Templates/projectspage.tpl"}'
```

I've tried with and without ' but nothing shows up within the div.  If i replace the module_webapps code with simple text like = 'demo' then text shows up.

Does anyone know if its possible to include this code in a script? Or even better is it possible to create a html select/option with javascript that can change an internal piece of the code, e.g change filter="all" to filter="waterprojects"

Thanks for the help

Comment: Looks like you need some kind of template engine to read that, since it's neither JavaScript or HTML.

Comment: http://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/developers/liquid/collection-parameter